# will my apps work on iphone OS4?

Tags: user-interface, screen, resolution, ios4, hardcoded

Screen resolution has increased in iphone OS4. Since lot of UI stuff have hardcoded co-ordinates, will my app run properly on OS4? I still haven't got Snow Leopard, so cant test run the simulator for OS4.

Answer (score 0):

It is publicly known that the number of points vs pixels is 2:1 so point 320 has 640 pixels in hi-res and 320 pixels in low-res. Low resolution images will be somewhat jaggy, but their positioning on the screen would remain the same.